# Creating corrupted PDF from bytearray

Tags: java, arrays, rest, pdf

I was trying to generate PDf from byte array in Java which was returned through webservice, But the PDF cannot be opened. It shows its corrupted, I have attached my code. Anyone pls help about where i got wrong?

```
       JSONObject o = new  JSONObject(outjson);
       JSONObject jsonob = o.optJSONObject("PDF details");
       byte[] pdfbyte=jsonob.optString("pdf bytearray").toString().getBytes();
       String str1 = new String(pdfbyte);
        File someFile = new File("C:/Users/acer/Desktop/test1.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
        byte[] byteData = str1.getBytes();
        byte[] byteData1 = test.getBytes();
        fos.write(pdfbyte);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
```

Following is my JSON from webservice:

```
{"PDF details": {
                "id":"121",
                 "pdf bytearray":"[B@62a58cd"
                 }
}
```

Following is my webservice code which outputs bytearray in json:

```
public Response getPdf(  )
{
    String flag=null;
    File file = new File("C:/Users/acer/Desktop/Report.pdf");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    byte[] data = null;
    byte[] finalData = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = null;


       fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
       data = new byte[(int)file.length()];
       finalData = new byte[(int)file.length()];
       byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       fileInputStream.read(data);
       byteArrayOutputStream.write(data);
       finalData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
       fileInputStream.close(); 


    System.out.println(finalData);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject mainjsonObject = new JSONObject();

    jsonObject.put("id","121");

    jsonObject.put("pdf bytearray",finalData);
    mainjsonObject.put("PDF details",jsonObject);
    flag = "" + mainjsonObject;

    return Response.status(200).entity(flag).build();

}
```

Comment: The `pdf bytearray` from your webservice is not valid. You need to fix the webservice.

Comment: i will attach my webservice code..pls check whethr the prblm is with it?

Comment: byte[].toString() doesn't generate a string containing the content of the byte array. Just a string containing the type of the array (`[B`), followed by `@` followed by a hashCode (`62a58cd`). You should be able to realize by yourself that a whole PDF document can't possibly fit into 10 characters. Use base-64 to transform the pdf bytes into a printable string, and vice-versa.

Comment: I already said it. Take a few minutes to read and digest my comment, think, and do some research. And while you're at it, avoid using spaces and random uppercase characters in the keys of your JSON objects. Use Java variable naming conventions: pdfDetails, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got it right with following chnge in my webservice:

```
public Response getPdf(  )
{
            String flag=null;
            File file = new File("C:/Users/acer/Desktop/Report.pdf");

            FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
            String encodedBase64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));

             JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
             JSONObject mainjsonObject = new JSONObject();

             jsonObject.put("id","121");

             jsonObject.put("pdf bytearray",encodedBase64);
             mainjsonObject.put("PDF details",jsonObject);
             flag = "" + mainjsonObject;


    return Response.status(200).entity(flag).build();
}
```

my Client:

```
     String encodedBase64=jsonob.optString("pdf bytearray");

     byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedBase64);
     System.out.println("decbyte   "+decodedBytes);
     File someFile = new File("C:/Users/acer/Desktop/test.pdf");
     OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
     fos.write(decodedBytes);
     fos.flush();
     fos.close();
```